# My wife is 26 and I am 30. We want catastrophic health insurance. If she is the policyholder, can we do this?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, affordable-care-act

Please do not reply with "you can't get catastrophic if you're not under 30". I know that. My question is can WE get it as a FAMILY PLAN if my 26-year-old wife is the policyholder.

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly this is not a great answer, but when I go to https://www.healthcare.gov/see-plans/, enter ZIP code 60647 (Cook County, Illinois), and then specify a married couple with no kids, both 29 years old, two catastrophic plans are available. When the age of either spouse is raised to 30, the catastrophic plans are no longer available. So I suspect the rule is both spouses must be younger than 30 to qualify for a catastrophic plan.

Answer (score 0):

The best suggestion I have is to check whether either of your employers offers such a plan as part of their benefits package. It is much easier to get that sort of insurance if you are part of a large group, so the insurance company has some statistics they can work with rather than trying to guess your individual risks.

Other than that, this is a shopping question, and all we can tell you is keep asking companies and hope you find one that can provide your needs. We don't know whether any of them will, and if we did, we don't know whether any of them will tomorrow... and stack exchange likes to think of itself as a long-term resource so answers which may elapse rapidly are discouraged.